# How to see when there are changes/enhancements to the CPython documentation

Tags: python

"What's new" sections, message boards, community, etc, are great, but what happens when a reference I've read, am familiar with, and may never look at again (or think I don't need to), gets a significant update.  I fear I may potentially miss the point of something useful when some new insightful examples or more complete documentation is created.  Perhaps, even the removal of incorrect or confusing documentation (GASP!).

Don't get me wrong, between Google Search, Stack Overflow, PEPs, and the well interlinked documentation, I usually am able to get as much detail as I want, very quickly. BUT as I gain familiarity with the language I would certainly like to review enhancements to such documentation if it's something I use often.

Is there a resource I can use to find this type of information already?

Comment: I'd say following the PEPs closely is the best way to keep in touch with significant changes.

Comment: @Lattyware Sounds like a reasonable strategy, but could you provide your reasoning behind it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If features are added or changed, we add 'version changed' or 'version added' entries to the docs.

If you want to (as it sounds like you do) monitor places where we improve the docs, then one way would be to subscribe to the python-checkins mailing list, and add a filter to your email program to only capture checkins that update the Doc subtree.

Alternatively you could do an hg checkout of the project, and periodically run 'hg log' against the Doc subtree and then take a closer look at any revisions that interest you.

Or, having the checkout, you can periodically do an 'hg diff' of the Doc directory between the last revision at which you did this and the then-current version.

Answer (score 2):

To see which files and how much have changed since a given revision:

```
$ hg diff --stat -r v3.3.0a1 Doc
Doc/library/copyreg.rst |   8 ++++--
Doc/library/pickle.rst  |  61 ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
2 files changed, 66 insertions(+), 3 deletions(-)
```

To skim through the changes:

```
$ hg diff -r v3.3.0a1 Doc | less
```

If you have found interesting changes you could [view them online](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/pickle#pickle.Pickler.dispatch_table).